# Shorten code to check conditions in switch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, switch-statement

How to short my code? To do not describe all the numbers.

```
func counter(_ count: Int) -> String {
    switch count {
    case 1, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 201, 221, 231, 241, 251, 261, 271, 281, 291, 301, 321, 331, 341, 351, 361, 371, 381, 391, 491, 501:
        return "\(searchAmong) \(count) \(photographer)"
    case 2...4, 22...24, 32...34, 42...44, 52...54, 62...64, 72...74, 82...84, 92...94, 102...104:
        return "\(searchAmong) \(count) \(photographerss)"
    case 5...20, 25...30, 35...40, 45...50, 55...60, 65...70, 75...80, 85...90, 95...100, 105...110:
        return "\(searchAmong) \(count) \(photographers)"
    default:
        let nothingToSearch = NSLocalizedString("Nothing to search :(", comment: "Нечего искать :(")
        return nothingToSearch
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't think you can really shorten it a lot, but you can shorten this function if you put the information e.g. in a dictionary like this

Comment: 1) Instead of switch move numbers to 3 arrays and check if given number are there. 2) If you know logic of these numbers you can calculate them instead of enumeration

Comment: Looks like that stuff belongs in a database, and not be hard-coded.

Comment: Is there some logic to your number series and how they are divided? What does `count` represent?

Comment: XY Problem, if you need localization of plurals, Apple already implemented it for you: [Stringsdict File Format](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/StringsdictFileFormat/StringsdictFileFormat.html). [Medium article explaining usage](https://medium.com/@vitaliikuznetsov/plurals-localization-using-stringsdict-in-ios-a910aab8c28c).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, those are pluralization rules (but I'm not sure it's English). First case is `one`, second is `few` and third one either `many` or `other`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide `count % 10` using modulo (remainder) operation. This will give you a number in range of 0 to 9 and checking will be much simpler.

```
func counter(_ count: Int) -> String {
   let rest = count % 10
   switch rest {
   case 1:
       return "\(searchAmong) \(count) \(photographer)"
   case 2...4:
       return "\(searchAmong) \(count) \(photographerss)"
   case 0, 5...9
       return "\(searchAmong) \(count) \(photographers)"       
   default:
       let nothingToSearch = NSLocalizedString("Nothing to search :(", comment: "Нечего искать :(")
       return nothingToSearch
   }
}
```

Comment: Very nice.  Find the patterns...

Comment: Doesn't work, it's not a consecutive series from 0 to 501 so for instance count = 498 should return `nothingToSearch`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for pointing it out, you're right. I assumed it's typical translation problem and not all possibilities were described in question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, maybe OP just got tired entering numbers post 501, and that's how this question came to life. You can't just fill case infinitely, but you can do it with mod like in this answer.

Comment: This does the wrong thing with 11, 12, 13, and 14.

Comment: @user28434 Not really interested in your speculations, I assume that OP has asked the question as it was meant to be asked.

Comment: @vacawama is right. I deleted my answer since there isn't a clear pattern in this situation. It has lots of limitations, and the solution isn't elegant anymore.